# Движение по лабиринту. 2.

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток. Есть код небольшого лабиринта, пытаюсь перенести движение игрока по лабиринту из класса *RealMaze* метода *keyPressed* в класс *Player*, но столкнулся с проблемой. Передаваемая переменная *x* изменяется, но возвращается неизменной и в результате движения вправо не происходит. Что нужно изменить?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/**
 * В этой программе осуществляется движение по лабиринту.
 * Передвигаться нужно с помощью стрелок.
 */

public class RealMaze implements KeyListener {

    //Начальные координаты игрока,
    public static int X = 0;
    public static int Y = 0;

    JButton button;
    MyDrawPanel myDrawPanel;
    JFrame frame;
    Player player = new Player();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        RealMaze realMaze = new RealMaze();
        realMaze.go();
    }

    public void go()throws Exception {

        //Отрисовка окна

        frame = new JFrame();
        myDrawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();
        button = new JButton();
        frame.setSize(500, 560);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, myDrawPanel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
        frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/IP44/Downloads/thinWall2.png")));
        button.addKeyListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)   {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        try {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();

            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                player.moveRight(map, X, Y);
                System.out.println("RealMaze x " + X);
            }


            if (map[X][Y] == 0 && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                Y--;
                if (map[X][Y] == 2) {
                    Y--;
                }
            }
            if (map[X][Y] == 0 && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                Y++;
                if (map[X][Y] == 2) {
                    Y++;
                }
            }

            frame.repaint();
        } catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)   {
    }

    class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)   {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            // Размер стороны квадрата.
            int sideLength = getSideLength();
            // Размер квадрата с учетом размера окна и размера массива.
            g.fillRect(X*sideLength, Y*sideLength, sideLength, sideLength);
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
        }

        private int getSideLength()   {
            // Минимальная сторона компоненты.
            int minComponentSide = (this.getHeight() > this.getWidth())  ? this.getWidth() : this.getHeight();
            // Максимальная сторона карты.
            int maxMapSide = (map.length > map[0].length) ? map.length : map[0].length;
            // Длина стороны, чтобы карта уместилась и комнаты были квадратные.
            return minComponentSide / maxMapSide;
        }
    }

    //Карта передвижения, 1 - стена, 2 - тонкая стена
    int[][] map = new int[][]{
            {0,0,2,0,0,0,0}, //x
            {0,0,2,0,0,0,0}, //|
            {0,0,1,0,0,0,0}, //|
            {0,0,1,1,2,2,2}, //|
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, //|
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, //|
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0}  //|
            // - - - - - y
    };
}




class Player {

    int moveRight(int[][] map, int x, int y) {

        System.out.println("Player x before " + x);

        if (map[x][y] == 0) {
            x++;
            if (map[x][y] == 2) {
                x++;
           }
        }

        System.out.println("Player x after " + x);

    return map[x][y];

    }
}
```